# How can I specify compiler flags to a single source file with qmake?

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qmake, qtcore

While other source files use the default flags? Some of my source files need some extra C++ preprocessor defines. I use Qt 5. I only found QMAKE_CXXFLAGS is for global use in [qmake](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Qmake) projects.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is what used to be done in theory for GUI painting in the Qt source itself:

```
SOURCES_NOOPTIMIZE = somefile.cpp
nooptimize.name = nooptimize
nooptimize.input = SOURCES_NOOPTIMIZE
nooptimize.dependency_type = TYPE_C
nooptimize.variable_out = OBJECTS
nooptimize.output = ${QMAKE_VAR_OBJECTS_DIR}${QMAKE_FILE_IN_BASE}$${first(QMAKE_EXT_OBJ)}
nooptimize.commands = $${QMAKE_CXX} $(CXXFLAGS) -O0 $(INCPATH) -c ${QMAKE_FILE_IN} -o ${QMAKE_FILE_OUT} # Note the -O0
QMAKE_EXTRA_COMPILERS += nooptimize
```

See also the advanced use [in the documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmake-advanced-usage.html#adding-compilers) how to add a compiler:

> Custom compiler specifications support the following members:
>
> Member    Description
>
> ***commands***    The commands used for for generating the output from the input.
>
> ***CONFIG***  Specific configuration options for the custom compiler. See the CONFIG table for details.
>
> ***depend_command***  Specifies a command used to generate the list of dependencies for the output.
>
> ***dependency_type*** Specifies the type of file the output is. If it is a known type (such as TYPE_C, TYPE_UI, TYPE_QRC), it is handled as one of those type of files.
>
> ***depends*** Specifies the dependencies of the output file.
>
> ***input***   The variable that specifies the files that should be processed with the custom compiler.
>
> ***name***    A description of what the custom compiler is doing. This is only used in some backends.
>
> ***output***  The filename that is created from the custom compiler.
>
> ***output_function*** Specifies a custom qmake function that is used to specify the filename to be created.
>
> ***variables***   Indicates that the variables specified here are replaced with $(QMAKE_COMP_VARNAME) when referred to in the pro file as $(VARNAME).
>
> ***variable_out***    The variable that the files created from the output should be added to.