# Specify compiler flags for a single file with QMake

Tags: c++, gcc, qmake

How is it possible to specify the compiler flags for a single source file using QMake .pro file?

Comment: You can find the detail [in this document](https://doc-snapshots.qt.io/qt5-5.4/qmake-advanced-usage.html#adding-compilers)

Comment: If possible avoid different flags for different files. At least use same optimization "solution" wise and same warnings "project" wise.

Comment: Is it possible to mit RTTI flag?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to specify compiler flag to a single source file with qmake?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27683777/how-to-specify-compiler-flag-to-a-single-source-file-with-qmake)

Answer (score -2):

Avoid using different flags for different files in a single build!

You should always find a baseline which works across the board. Mixing flags can cause complications when invalid code from one file interferes with perspectively valid code from another, etc. These files are being built together and therefore they need to be compiled together and uniformly.

Comment: I agree with you, it would be only a temporary solution. But it would be necessary to solve it. And I am also interested in that :).