# Different Warning flags for different files in Qt

Tags: c++, qt, qmake

I have one large `codebase` project in `Qt`. I have been using two third party libraries: [json](https://github.com/open-source-parsers/jsoncpp) and [QSimpleUpdater](https://github.com/alex-spataru/QSimpleUpdater). Since, these libraries are external, their source files generates alot of warnings. I can't and don't want to change those external libraries. I want to add different compiler flags for different folders.

For example, source code except external libraries should be compiled with following warnings:

```
QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += -Wall -Wextra -Wshadow -Wno-unused-parameter
```

And external libraries should be compiled with:

```
QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += -Wall
```

I tried to find answers over stackoverflow and came across [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27683777/how-to-specify-compiler-flag-to-a-single-source-file-with-qmake) question but that question specify how to add another compiler for the project but i need just to have different warning flags for different files.

Comment: this might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5801754/gcc-directory-option-isystem . the `-isystem` basically allows you to select include folders where warnings are ignored

Comment: This is normally done on per-project level. You should consider using a global `SUBDIRS` type of project, along with distinct subprojects for your application and libraries used.